# htaccess set session timeout

Tags: php, .htaccess

i need to set the session timeout, i need it to be at least 8 hours, and i don't have access to the php.ini file, so can this be done in .htaccess?

this is my htaccess, the 10 is just for the test, after 10 seconds the session is still alive so i assume is not setting the value correctly.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    #Session timeout
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 10
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10
</IfModule>

# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and this is the php code

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 10);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10);
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    header("Location: login");
}
```

how can i achieve this? by the way the server is running php 5.6, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `.htaccess` you need to set `session.cookie_lifetime` as a string

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime "10"
```

In PHP you set it with `session_set_cookie_params()`. See [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)